# Evaluating an expression with multiple boolean values

Tags: java

This might seem quite straight forward to most of the programmers, but I was a little surprised to see the following code print `true`.

```
//The actual implementation has proper logic, 
//just for simplicity I am using booleans in place of those logics

System.out.println(false && false || true && true || false && false);
```

Because my perception was that - if the 1st boolean value evaluates to `false` and the next operand is `&&` then the jvm will not even try to evaluate the rest of the expression and just consider the whole as `false`

I was expecting code like below to work, but not the above one:

```
System.out.println((false && false) || (true && true) || (false && false));
```

Is it like the compiler by default groups the `&&`s between `||`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it like the compiler by default groups the &&s between ||s

That's exactly what it does.  It's called [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).  Languages explicitly define it because otherwise operations could be ambiguous, and ambiguity can't be allowed by a compiler.

A simpler example of operator precendence would be something like:

```
x = 1 + 2 * 3;
```

Would you expect the result to be 9 or 7?  Operator precedence defines unambiguously what the result must be.